# How to embed in Facebook FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I use that code to login with Facebook:

```
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"user_birthday", @"email"]
                                allowLoginUI:YES

                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

         if (error)
         {
         NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
         }

          if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
          {
         [self getPermissions];
          }
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
```

I want to insert webView with FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView, I tried any combinations but I lost control of my app, how can use both that methods? I want Facebook web view with behavior, methods and Permissions of openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully implemented this on iPhone and iPad, but I am currently having an issue.  Here's the code I am using

```
    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email"]];
[FBSession setActiveSession:session];
[session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];
}];
```

The issue I am having is on iPhone, the dialog comes up, but the only thing that is seen is the spinning progress indicator.  On iPad, it is working fine for me, but our QA group only sees the spinning progress indicator on both devices.